# Heroku port number for a given application

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

how to view heroku port number for a given application?

I tried to use "heroku config:get PORT" command.but windows command prompt gave the result as " !    No app specified ". what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port number is not per-application, but per-dyno. Only your dyno has that information.
And you don't need to get it externally either. No matter which port is set for that dyno, your app will always be available externally on port 80.

Comment: I want to use java websocket api and I need to mention a port number in client side code for connect with my back end that hosted on heroku. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: The port is 80 then, and the hostname is <appname>.herokuapp.com

Comment: Thank you! I will check.